# Problem driving IPB065N15N3G MOSFET with HCPL-316J driver

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I want to drive an [IPB065N15N3G MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPB065N15N3G-DS-v02_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30432662379201266a0379d1225c). I am making a boost converter. The driver I am using is the [HCPL-316J](https://www.impedanca.si/media/HCPL-316J-000E.pdf) (a combined optocoupler and driver). Below is a picture of my schematic.

Please tell me what is the problem in this schematic and why can I not get the desired output? Since I am providing a triangular wave, why is the gate of the MOSFET not driven?

[image: Schematic]

Since the HCPL-316J is not available in CircuitLab, I am providing [a link to a Google drive with the Spice model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11fQoUgDcAxcsyklvNGTDUSS6u6zzsWEY/view?usp=sharing). It is a .asc file. Please use LTspice XVII to open the file.

```
          -----------X-----------X--------------X------------
```

I redesigned the circuit using nodes. Also added and replaced some components in the circuit.[image: New circuit]
The voltage at drain is like this:[image: Vds]
The voltage at gate is like this:[image: Vgs]
As we can see there is no pulse at the gate, so the mosfet can not switch on and off.

```
       ------------X-----------------X------------------X-------------
```

After simulating the above circuit, I am trying to simulate the same circuit with different mosfet.[Datasheet of mosfet is here.](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stf27n60m2-ep.pdf) Please suggest what should be the necessary modifications to be made in order for the circuit to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**V2 and the HCPL-316J don't have GND connection.**
See picture below.

[image]

You should better start cleaning up the schematic first.
**Use nodes**. Remove all wired connection to GND and replace them by short connection to the GND node. Cut the traces of the voltage sources V1, V2, etc. Give their positive terminal a node and use these nodes to make *short* connections to other components.
In the picture above, I showed the idea for voltage source V1.

PS. Please turn off the grid when posting a schematic.

---

**VCC2 (w.r.t. to VE) does not exceed the UVLO Threshold**

In the schematic, VCC2 is only 5V and therefore the HCPL-316J will be in UVLO.
In the **Notes** on page 10 of the datasheet of HCPL-316J:

> 9. 15 V is the recommended minimum operating positive supply voltage (VCC2 - VE) to ensure adequate margin in excess of the maximum VUVLO+ threshold of 13.5 V. For High Level Output Voltage testing, VOH is measured with a dc load current. When driving capacitive loads, VOH will approach VCC as IOH approaches zero units.

The recommended voltage for (VCC2-VE) is between 15V and 30V. Vout will become about this voltage. 
**DO NOTE that (most) mosfets have the absolute maximum rating V<sub>GS</sub> < 20V.**

---

I haven't gone into details with the datasheet, but I think this driver is specially designed to drive **IGBT's**. I think you'd better pick a different IC when driving mosfets.
Regarding simulation: I got better simulation results by shorting/disabling the Integrated Desaturation (VCE) Detection to ground.
BTW, You don't need V4, because it is only needed when negative gate drive is implemented.

---

Although it is not hurting the simulation, better also comply to the datasheet's Absolute Maximum Ratings:

```
Parameter           Symbol                   Min.    Max.
Input Pin Voltages  VIN+, VIN- and VRESET    -0.5    VCC1
```

So, change V1 to `PULSE(0 5 0 12.5u 12.5u 0 25.0u)`

---

**WORKING SIMULATION**
Note I did **not use MUR1100**. It takes ages on my PC to simulate with it. Moreover, I questioned before why you want to use this DESAT pin or actually even this **IGBT** driver. I got almost the same results by deleting this D1 and connecting the 100 ohm resistor to GND.
For clarity, I also removed almost all caps that are connected directly across a voltage source (except for C2) because in *simulation* these caps don't do anything. (But do add them on the real PCB!)
You should look at the diagram on page 3: that reveals why applying a negative voltage on VINN is useless; better connect it to GND. The same for the pulse source / *positive* triangular pulse source connected to VINP.
I connected a 1 Meg to LED1 in order to see the output of the internal  comparator.  For your PCB, the datasheet suggest to leave LED1 and LED2 *unconnected*.

[image]

Comment: @SiddharthSingh Please find an updated answer. **In short: VCC2 (w.r.t. to VE) does not exceed the UVLO Threshold**

Comment: @SiddharthSingh In your updated schematic: connect VINN of HCPL-316J to GND. And connect VINP of HCPL-316J to the PULSE(...) source. Connect a 1 Meg resistor to LED1 of HCPL-316J and to GND as in your original circuit. Measure/plot the LED1 pin of HCPL-316J

Comment: @SiddharthSingh BTW, you can replace all the textual nodes GND by the triangle ground symbol

Comment: @SiddharthSingh Please find a working simulation in my updated answer. Do note I will not open google drive links or other unknown links. I'm happy to help, but update your original post with added new screenshots. Good luck making this thing working!

Comment: I am trying the above circuit with different mosfet. [Datasheet is here.](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stf27n60m2-ep.pdf) Please can you tell me what modifications should be made in the circuit?

Comment: The characteristics of this mosfet are slightly different. The mosfet's gate resistor (Intrinsic gate resistance) changes from 2.3 ohm to 4 ohm. Therefore, you could adjust the *external* gate resistor from 4.4 ohm to 2.7 ohm. However, the Dynamic characteristics are different as well and lowering the external resistor may turn on the mosfet too fast. So, bottom line: play around with this resistor while simulation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am also going to use different mosfet driver. [The driver is ACPL 337J.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/V02-4390EN_DS_ACPL-337J_2014-05-09-909393.pdf)  What are new connections that are to be made in the circuit so that it works.

Comment: Hi @Huisman, your DESAT voltage has reached values over 7V during some cycles, shouldn't it activate the fault status and turn off Vout?

Comment: @IronMaiden Page 24 of the HCPL-316J datasheet: *"If an IGBT desaturation fault is detected **while the signal LED is on**, the Fault signal will latch in the high state."* I can see in simulation the LED is low for those cases. (i.e. the driving input is low). See also Figure 64. *Behavioral circuit schematic.* in the datasheet.

Comment: @Huisman indeed it works accordingly, but when the fault condition is activated the circuit would only be able to function again if reset is pulled low, and in your circuit it's always low since you grounded the RESET pin. I mean, why did you ground it? Shouldn't it receive a signal from a uC so later it'd work again? You kinda disabled the DESAT function, is that the case?

Comment: I started with OP's original circuit where it RESET was tied to VINN. I think I also thoughtlessly tied RESET to GND when I wrote: *"that reveals why applying a negative voltage on VINN is useless; better connect it to GND. "* **So, you're right: RESET should no be connected to GND, it should be implemented such that the HCPL-316J can be reset.**